# With one installation on Server how can we achieve different landing pages and customization that shows the appropriate logos?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, jasperserver

I am using *JasperReport Server 4.0.0* running on *Apache Tomcat*.

I can access it using this url: `http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/login.html`

now I copied *JR Server* directory from

```
C:\Program Files\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver
```

as

```
C:\Program Files\jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\myjasper
```

If I try to launch application using this url: `http://localhost:8080/myjasper/login.html` it should work but it doesn't work.

I have tried in other way, by renaming **jasperserver** to **myjasper** and it worked for me but I want to keep both.

My question is how can I use both url to access *JR Server*?

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't really enough detail for someone to guess what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two separate instances of JasperReports Server, then use the .war file install. You can do a fresh install and call the new instance "myjasper".

EDIT: Don't rename the folder. The included Install Guide documentation explains how to do the .war file install. The specific property you are looking for in default_master.properties is webAppNameCE. Set that to "myjasper" rather than its default value of "jasperserver". Then it will get install to the folder that you want, and all corresponding configuration files will be set correctly as well.

If you want different look-and-feel for different organizations while managing them all in the same repository, then you have this ability in the commercial edition of JRS. The themes can be applied separately to different organizations or "tenants".

Comment: I installed JasperReport Server using .war file install and then I renamed jasperserver folder to myjasper under tomcat/webapps directory, now I can access it using this                          url:http://localhost:8080/myjasper/login.html but if I install again a new instance of jasperserver using the same Tomcat and mysql, its showing the same HTTP Status 404 - /jasperserver/login.html error. Is there any other way to have two instances of jasper server in the same Tomcat and MySQL?

Comment: Don't rename the folder. I'll add some detail to the answer.